# Firebase query filter is undefined when using IN clause which causes all documents to be returned

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to perform a query using the [in](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_and_array-contains-any) clause for firebase but am being returned all documents within the collection.

I have the following method

```
export async function getDocumentsWithCriteria(path, field, operation, criteria) {
    const query = firebase.firestore().collection(path).where(field, operation, criteria);
    console.log('query: ', query);
    return await query.get()
        .then(querySnapshot => { ... })
}
```

which I call using

```
let usernames = ["sicnarf", "shmoey"];
getDocumentsWithCriteria("users", "username", "in", usernames)
```

The console.log statement in the first snippet prints out [image: Query]

After debugging for a bit I realized that the *operator* field within Firebase's query is *undefined*. Should this behavior be expected? Why does this only happen for the **in** clause? For instance, using "==" instead of "in" results in the *operator* having a value of "EQUAL".

Comment: Two things 1) That screenshot is incredibly difficult to read. Please don't show screenshots of text on Stack Overflow - it's better to copy the text into the question itself. 2) Why exactly are you concerned about that output?  You're looking at Firestore implementation details.  If the query isn't working the way you expect, you should describe what your code is doing.

Comment: @DougStevenson My question is why does **operator** have a value of undefined when passing _in_ as it's value? I'm trying to find all documents at path _users_ where _username_ is within the _usernames_ array.

Comment: Why are you concerned about this implementation detail?  Does the query not work the way you expect?  As the caller of the API, that's really all you need to know - does this call work or not.

Comment: @DougStevenson It does not work. It returns all documents in the "users" collection

Comment: I suggest editing the question to give more details about what is not working the way you expect from an API perspective, not involving the implementation details.  Focus on the results of the API and how they don't meet your expectations.